# I Want Result1 while Executing the SQL Query2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

**I Want to Result1 while executing the Query2 in below sql.**

In Query2 I Added group by elements. Hence i am getting multiple rows.

Query 1:

```
Declare @LedgerId int;
set @LedgerId=47;
Declare @FirmId int;
set @FirmId=8;
declare @FromDate Datetime;
set @FromDate='01-09-2015';
declare @ToDate datetime;
set @ToDate='03-21-2015';

SELECT DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0, @FromDate), -1) as [Date]
    ,IIF(Isnull(Sum(a.[Credit]),0) > ISNULL(SUM(a.Debit),0), ISNULL(SUM(a.Credit),0) - ISNULL(SUM(a.Debit),0),  ISNULL(SUM(a.Credit),0)) as Debit
    ,IIF(Isnull(Sum(a.debit),0) > ISNULL(SUM(a.credit),0), ISNULL(SUM(a.debit),0) - ISNULL(SUM(a.credit),0),    ISNULL(SUM(a.debit),0)) as Credit

  FROM [vwLedgerBalance_Reports] a

  WHERE a.[Date] between '01-01-1990' and DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0, @FromDate), -1) 
  and a.[FirmEntryID] = @FirmId 
  and a.LedgerId = @LedgerId
```

Result 1 (I am expecting):

```
[Date]          [Debit]     [Credit]
2015-01-08      1420710.00  0.00
```

Query 2:

```
Declare @LedgerId int;
set @LedgerId=47;
Declare @FirmId int;
set @FirmId=8;
declare @FromDate Datetime;
set @FromDate='01-09-2015';
declare @ToDate datetime;
set @ToDate='03-21-2015';

SELECT DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0, @FromDate), -1) as [Date]
   ,'Opening Balance ' as [Description]
   ,a.[LedgerId]
   ,a.[FirmEntryID]      
    ,IIF(Isnull(Sum(a.[Credit]),0) > ISNULL(SUM(a.Debit),0), ISNULL(SUM(a.Credit),0) - ISNULL(SUM(a.Debit),0), ISNULL(SUM(a.Credit),0)) as Debit
    ,IIF(Isnull(Sum(a.debit),0) > ISNULL(SUM(a.credit),0), ISNULL(SUM(a.debit),0) - ISNULL(SUM(a.credit),0), ISNULL(SUM(a.debit),0)) as Credit

  FROM [vwLedgerBalance_Reports] a

  WHERE a.[Date] between '01-01-1990' and DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0, @FromDate), -1) 
  and a.[FirmEntryID] = @FirmId 
  and a.LedgerId = @LedgerId 
  group by a.[Date], a.[Description],a.[LedgerId],a.[FirmEntryID]
```

Result 2:

```
Date                    Description    LedgerId FirmEntryID Debit   Credit
2015-01-08 00:00:00.000 Opening Balance     47  8   892210.00   0.00
2015-01-08 00:00:00.000 Opening Balance     47  8   32850.00    0.00
2015-01-08 00:00:00.000 Opening Balance     47  8   171200.00   0.00
2015-01-08 00:00:00.000 Opening Balance     47  8   324450.00   0.00
```

I am calculating the Ledger Balance. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Since your result set has the same values in grouped columns and you are grouping by those columns, it is obvious that Description column or Date have different values. So just exclude Description and Date from grouping since you are selecting constant values `'Opening Balance '` and `DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0, @FromDate), -1)`:

```
DECLARE @LedgerId INT;
SET @LedgerId = 47;
DECLARE @FirmId INT;
SET @FirmId = 8;
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME;
SET @FromDate = '01-09-2015';
DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME;
SET @ToDate = '03-21-2015';

SELECT  DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0, @FromDate), -1) AS [Date] ,
        'Opening Balance ' AS [Description] ,
        a.[LedgerId] ,
        a.[FirmEntryID] ,
        IIF(ISNULL(SUM(a.[Credit]), 0) > ISNULL(SUM(a.Debit), 0), ISNULL(SUM(a.Credit),
                                                          0)
        - ISNULL(SUM(a.Debit), 0), ISNULL(SUM(a.Credit), 0)) AS Debit ,
        IIF(ISNULL(SUM(a.debit), 0) > ISNULL(SUM(a.credit), 0), ISNULL(SUM(a.debit),
                                                          0)
        - ISNULL(SUM(a.credit), 0), ISNULL(SUM(a.debit), 0)) AS Credit
FROM    [vwLedgerBalance_Reports] a
WHERE   a.[Date] BETWEEN '01-01-1990'
                 AND     DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0, @FromDate), -1)
        AND a.[FirmEntryID] = @FirmId
        AND a.LedgerId = @LedgerId
GROUP BY a.[LedgerId] ,
        a.[FirmEntryID]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;WITH tbl AS (SELECT DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0, @FromDate), -1) as [Date]
   ,'Opening Balance ' as [Description]
   ,a.[LedgerId]
   ,a.[FirmEntryID]      
    ,IIF(Isnull(Sum(a.[Credit]),0) > ISNULL(SUM(a.Debit),0), ISNULL(SUM(a.Credit),0) - ISNULL(SUM(a.Debit),0), ISNULL(SUM(a.Credit),0)) as Debit
    ,IIF(Isnull(Sum(a.debit),0) > ISNULL(SUM(a.credit),0), ISNULL(SUM(a.debit),0) - ISNULL(SUM(a.credit),0), ISNULL(SUM(a.debit),0)) as Credit

  FROM [vwLedgerBalance_Reports] a

  WHERE a.[Date] between '01-01-1990' and DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0, @FromDate), -1) 
  and a.[FirmEntryID] = @FirmId 
  and a.LedgerId = @LedgerId )

  SELECT
    [Date],[Description],a.[LedgerId],a.[FirmEntryID],ISNULL(sum(Debit),0),ISNULL(sum(Credit),0)
  FROM
    tbl group by tbl.[Date], tbl.[Description],tbl.[LedgerId],tbl.[FirmEntryID],tbl.[Debit],tbl.[Credit]
```